# Custom reorder a list based off another list in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

I have a 2d lists:

```
{{"Porsche", "Blue"}, {"Ferrari", "Red"}, {"Honda", "Green"}, {"Lambo", "Black"}}
```

I want to reorder the list based off a custom order of the first child element. So I provide a list maybe that looks like the following:

```
{"Ferrari", "Honda", "Porsche", "Lambo"} /*or perhaps even:*/ {2,3,1,4}
```

and it will return the reordered original List in this new order I've given, with the colors intact:

```
{{"Ferrari", "Red"}, {"Honda", "Green"}, {"Porsche", "Blue"}, {"Lambo", "Black"}}
```

Is that possible in C#?

Comment: Could you show us your code? what's your sample data format? it didn't look like `JSON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can work with the below concept:

**Concept:**

1. Cast 2d array to `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.
2. Join with *result 1* by key and return the result (Outcome: Nested List / Multidimensional array).

```cs
using System.Linq;

var lookup = inputs.Select((value, index) => new { brand = value[0], array = value })
    .ToLookup(x => x.brand, x => x.array);

var order = new List<string>{"Ferrari", "Honda", "Porsche", "Lambo"};
var orderList = (from o in order
    join l in lookup on o equals l.Key
    select l
    ).ToArray();
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vN1feV)

> Output

```
[["Ferrari","Red"],["Honda","Green"],["Porsche","Blue"],["Lambo","Black"]]
```

---

**Side note:**

In case the 2d array data **contains multiple records same brand**, then you need `.SelectMany()` to flatten the result after joining the order array/list and 2d array.

```cs
string[][] inputs = new string[][]
{ 
    new string[] {"Porsche", "Blue"}, 
    new string[] {"Ferrari", "Red"}, 
    new string[] {"Honda", "Green"}, 
    new string[] {"Lambo", "Black"},
    new string[] {"Ferrari", "Yellow"}, 
};

var lookup = inputs.Select((value, index) => new { brand = value[0], array = value })
    .ToLookup(x => x.brand, x => x.array);

var order = new List<string>{"Ferrari", "Honda", "Porsche", "Lambo"};
var orderList = (from o in order
    join l in lookup on o equals l.Key
    select l
    )
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToArray();
```

[Sample program (Flatten array for same brands)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3M8sPE)